# Acessar playlist music Android

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um APP para *Android*, que preciso de acessar a playlist de músicas, no caso seria da seguinte forma carregaria uma tela inicial com as playlists que possui e uma categoria com todas musicas, e clicando na playlist desejada exibe as músicas daquela playlist selecionada, e o próprio APP tem de ter permissão de executar músicas nele mesmo.

Alguém tem alguma idéia de como fazer, um código de exemplo ou um mini projeto exemplar? Minha duvida é de como acessar as musicas que ja existem no meu celular e como acessar as playlists ja criadas no próprio celular. Um exemplo de App que faz isso é o da Nike. E como fazer a Execução das musicas?

Comment: Leonardo, de uma olhada nesses sites, eles tem alguns exemplos de como criar um player: 
[1] http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/
[2] http://alucard1990.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Make-a-Simple-Media-Player-for-Android

Comment: Acho que a duvida dele é acessar as playlists do app Play Music da google, é isso? Ou apenas criar uma playlist?

Comment: @Wakim minha duvida é de como acessar as musicas que ja existem no meu celular e como acessar as playlists ja criadas no próprio celular. Um exemplo de App que faz isso é o da Nike.

Comment: @Marabita preciso de acessar as musicas que ja existem no celular e não as que forem adicionadas ao App.

Comment: @LeonardoPatricio Você pode obter as musicas de dentro do sdcard, já as musicas do 'play music' acho mais complicado pois provavelmente estão protegidas por DRM.

Comment: Mas é possível de alguma forma pois o app da Nike ou o do 4shared consegue acessa-las.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o que você procura é exatamente a API de [`MediaStorage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) do Android.

Ela possui tanto formas de acessar qualquer tipo de mídia que esteja em armazenamento interno e externo do dispositivo.

Para obter todas as músicas do aparelho, de uma olhada no [`MediaStorage.Audio`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html) e para obter as playlists gravadas no dispositivo de uma olhada em [`MediaStorage.Audio.PlayLists`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.html).

Achei um tutorial completo para montar um app de **Music Player** utilizando essa API, nesse [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764).

Você terá que usar um ContentResolver para fazer uma `Query` sobre músicas e PlayLists. Teria algo como:

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

// Iterar sobre o cursor...
```

Abaixo o código para tocar uma música usando o [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) a partir do `Cursor`, a partir desta pergunta do [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035999/androidpick-songs-from-sd-card-and-play-it):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
    int music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

    musicCursor.moveToPosition(position);

    String filename = musicCursor.getString(music_column_index);

    try {
          if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())  {
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
          }

          mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
          mMediaPlayer.prepare();
          mMediaPlayer.start();

          mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
              @Override
              public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                  mp.release();
                  mp = null;                                   
              }
          });     
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Nesse código, é feita uma consulta por todas as músicas do dispositivo.

Para consultar as playlists, achei um `snippet`, sem fonte confiável que segue o mesmo princípio da consulta de músicas:

```
public void checkforplaylists(Context context) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String id = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID;
    final String name = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME;
    final String[] columns = {id, name};

    final Cursor playlists = cr.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);

    if(playlists == null) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Found no playlists.");
        return;
    }

    Log.e(TAG,"Found playlists.");

    // Iterar sobre o cursor...
}
```

Comment: Vlw Fera, realmente isso ajudou eu consegui visualizar as musicas armazenadas no cel, porém o tutorial não ensina como executar as musicas. Mas está sendo de grande ajuda.

Comment: Ah sim, executar as músicas é outro ponto. Teria que ver melhor isso.

Comment: Poderia incluir isso na pergunta?

Comment: é pois quando clico em uma música da lista o app está parando de funcionar. No caso pois está faltando um methodos chamada songPicked.

Comment: Poste na pergunta o código que tem.

Comment: @LeonardoPatricio, inclui mais um trecho para tocar a música.

Comment: Qual o tipo dessa variavel "mMediaPlayer"?

Comment: É uma instância da classe `MediaPlayer`, coloquei um link na resposta.